# ASP.Net Drop Down Generator

Tags: asp.net

I really didnt know what the title would be as i am not very good with words and describing so i hope my title makes since for what i am trying to accomplish.

What I am making is basically a page that with fields populated will put those fields into pre-coded text which when the button is clicked it will place the text correctly. I got that part completed, however what i am needing is to be able to select different models and have the pre-populated text be based on the drop down selection.

Here is my code (some have been taken out due to security so i am only giving what i can)

```
    <script runat="server">
     Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    lbl1.Text = "configure terminal"
    lbl2.Text = "hostname " & clabb.Text & "-340-" & conumb.Text & "." & cpenum.Text
    lbl3.Text = "ip address " & ip.Text & "." & conumb.Text & "." & cpenum.Text & subnet.Text

    <form runat="server">
    Client Abbreviation: <asp:TextBox id="clabb" runat="server" /><br />
    Client IP: <asp:TextBox id="ip" runat="server" /><br />
    Client Subnet: <asp:TextBox id="subnet" runat="server" /><br />
    Client Gateway: <asp:TextBox id="gateway" runat="server" /><br />
    CO Number: <asp:TextBox id="conumb" runat="server" /><br />
    CPE Number: <asp:TextBox id="cpenum" runat="server" /><br />
    Mgmt Vlan: <asp:TextBox id="mgmtvlan" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Button OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" /><br /><br />
    <asp:Label id="lbl1" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Label id="lbl2" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Label id="lbl3" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Label id="lbl4" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Label id="lbl5" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Label id="lbl6" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Label id="lbl7" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Label id="lbl8" runat="server" /><br />
    </form>
```

My problem is that i cannot really find anything online for what i am trying to do. I am not an expert on this but i am trying to learn so if someone replies please explain as best you can.

Thanks,

Comment: are you tring to dynamicly populate the dropdown

Comment: No, i would have prepopulated selections.

Comment: -3550
-3560
-3348
-340

for example.

Comment: are you trying to get the value of the selected item??

Comment: no basically how i have the code above where the labels are set. I want it so that if i select 3550 it will have the labels set to certain text and if i select 3560 itll have different text and so on... make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in event `onselectedindexchanged` your asp .net dom dropdown should be like this :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="yourlist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="itemSelectedChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and create the event handler

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AJAX which means that the page would not need a PostBack (i.e. the page would refresh - load again.)

However, for a less complicated way, use the code behind.

So, let's say that you have a State dropdown and based on the selected State, you would select a city.

Your state dropdown would be:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="cboState" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

and your city dropdown would be:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then, when the user selects a value you would get a PostBack.

Your code behind would be:

```
 Protected Sub cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboCity.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cboCity.Text = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Pseudo code
    strSQL = "SELECT city FROM locations WHERE some_state = '" & cboState.Text & "' ORDER BY city ASC"

    'Run the SQL query and fill the city dropdown
    cboCity.Items.Add(--the city field--)
End Sub
```

I've tried to make this as inclusive as possible, please let me know if you have issues with this code.